# Text should be printed in new line when text is longer than field width

Tags: jasper-reports

I am really new to JasperReports and have the following issue:

I would like to print the date with time zone in some colum but the colum width is not enough for printing the date:

[image]

How to tell jasper that it has to print the time zone in new line? something like this:

```
2016-07-07 16:32:35 +02:00 
EUROPE/BERLIN
```

I use Jaspersoft iReport Desinger 4.7.0.

**UPDATE:**

the field looks like this:

```
<field name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
..
..
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="6e3cbfd4-f1e9-453f-b3d8-39ae6231931d" key="element-1863" style="column details" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="626" y="0" width="216" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
..
....
```

Comment: What is the output format? What is a source of text (field, parameter)? It is better to post the sample (*jrxml* file)

Comment: @AlexK date is a field

Comment: @AlexK I have updated the question

Comment: You can use two variables or expression with two parts of date and "\n" symbol. I know that it is not the nice solution. Another way is to use scriptlet for breaking line or JR framework's source code customization